# target in href not switching to existing tab in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement to switch to an existing tab when click on a hyperlink. I did that with the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_yoy">click me</a>

</body>
</html>
```

It worked well in Chrome and Firefox but when i try in IE11, first time it  open the new tab but next time onward it is not switching to that existing open tab. Looks like it is highlighted but not switched. Please help.

Comment: Do you want to open all further links on your initial page to open in the same new tab? I'm afraid (but not entirely sure) this is only possible with JS (e.g. `window.open`). Also, I'm not aware of the `_yoy` target. If you only want to open links in a new tab, consider using `_blank`.

Comment: I do not want to use _blank it will always create a new tab. I want to switch to the tab if it is already open. With JS window.open i tried and gt the same behavior. it Simply try to focus the existing tab but not switching. Only IE i have this problem. Chrome and Firefox it works well.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, MSIE is weird, with both the `form` `target` attribute, and with `a`, it has "interesting" behaviour with `target="<frame name>"`.

[This answer should work for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24942420/3513171)

Comment: Any solution we have to switch to the existing tab in IE? I tried with window.open as well but got the same problem.

Comment: Any solution to this problem in IE? Please let me know.